# Problems with 'seeding' data to different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to seed some data to my wiki model user the 'faker gem'. I have created three users and would like to 'spread' 20 wikis over them.

I installed the faker gem, run bundle and set up my seedfile like this:

```
 require 'faker'
# Create an admin user
admin = User.new(
email:    'admin2@example.com',
password: 'helloworld',
role:     'administrator'
)

admin.save!

# Create a moderator
moderator = User.new(
email:    'moderator2@example.com',
password: 'helloworld',
role:     'moderator'
)

moderator.save!

# Create a member
member = User.new(
email:    'member2@example.com',
password: 'helloworld'
)

member.save!

users = User.all


15.times do
 Wiki.create!(
  title: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
  body:  Faker::Lorem.paragraph
  user:  users.sample
  )
  end
  wikis = Wiki.all
  puts "Seeds finished"
```

If I run this I get an error:

```
 SyntaxError: /Users/marcvanderpeet/Projects/bloc/blocipedia/db/seeds.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
 user:  users.sample
```

I dont understand why I get this error as when Im running rails c I can just type in a user:

```
  2.1.5 :001 > u = Wiki.new
```

=> #

Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error: the line

```
body:  Faker::Lorem.paragraph
```

should end with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Already got it, forgot a ','. Devil is in the details!